# Replace the values of a row based on a dictionary

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Var1    Var2
rs123     ADH6
rs123     ADH6
rs123     ADH6
rs123     ?
rs56756   CYP4V2
rs56756   ?
rs56756   ?
rs98    NUP62
rs98    ?
rs98    NUP62
rs98    NUP62
```

As you can see, all rs have one value for Var2, and maybe a missing value.

And I also have a dictionary:

```
Var1    Var2
rs123     ADH6
rs56756   CYP4V2
rs98    NUP62
```

I want to change every missing value in var2 of the first dataframe, for the correspondent value in the dictionary.

RepEx for getting the dataframe and the dictionary

```
library(dplyr)

first_column <- c("rs1","rs1","rs1","rs2","rs2","rs2","rs2","rs2","rs3","rs3","rs3","rs3","rs3")
second_column <- c("APOA","APOA",NA,"SIGMA",NA,NA,"SIGMA","SIGMA","SIGMA","ALPHA","ALPHA",NA,NA)


df <- data.frame(first_column, second_column)
df_noNa <- df[!is.na(df$second_column),]

df1 <- df_noNa %>%
  group_by(second_column) %>%
  count(first_column, second_column) %>%
  slice(which.max(n)) %>%
  select(-n)
```

Comment: The dataframes are not the same. Var1[1] = "rs123"  but first_column[1] = "rs1".  So `df ` which is reproducible does not match the dataset shown as a table. Could you please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the `first_column` elements so they agree with the dictionary and table.

```r
library(dplyr)

first_column <- rep(c("rs123", "rs56756", "rs98"), c(3, 5, 5))
second_column <- c("APOA","APOA",NA,"SIGMA",NA,NA,"SIGMA","SIGMA","SIGMA","ALPHA","ALPHA",NA,NA)

df <- data.frame(first_column, second_column)

dic <- structure(list(Var1 = c("rs123", "rs56756", "rs98"), 
                      Var2 = c("ADH6", "CYP4V2", "NUP62")), 
                 class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df |> 
  left_join(dic, by = c("first_column" = "Var1")) |> 
  mutate(second_column = ifelse(is.na(second_column), Var2, second_column)) |> 
  select(-Var2)
#>    first_column second_column
#> 1         rs123          APOA
#> 2         rs123          APOA
#> 3         rs123          ADH6
#> 4       rs56756         SIGMA
#> 5       rs56756        CYP4V2
#> 6       rs56756        CYP4V2
#> 7       rs56756         SIGMA
#> 8       rs56756         SIGMA
#> 9          rs98         SIGMA
#> 10         rs98         ALPHA
#> 11         rs98         ALPHA
#> 12         rs98         NUP62
#> 13         rs98         NUP62
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>